# How to use Vagrant with VirtualBox AND kvm-qemu installed?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 machine that has both VirtualBox and libvirt/kvm-qemu installed.

Whenever I try to bring up a Vagrant box with the VirtualBox prodiver, I get this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/xenial64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20170626.0.0'. The latest is version '20170717.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: mainframe_default_1500383484218_22222
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "ab19fdfd-349e-40d0-b540-aa130b9e1b72", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is being used by another hypervisor (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
VBoxManage: error: VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Is there a way to use VirtualBox and Vagrant when kvm-qemu is also present?

This is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.66.10"
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = 'playbook.yml'
  end
end
```

I don't want to use the libvirt provider because it has less boxes, and I have to manually edit every Vagrantfile I use.

How can I use Vagrant with VirtualBox when both VirtualBox and libvirt/kvm-qemu are present?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, somewhat by chance. It's possible to have both installed, but it's not possible to have them both run VMs at the same time.

If I shutdown every VM in libvirt, then I can run Vagrant and VirtualBox. If I need a machine from libvirt, then I have to shutdown every VitrualBox VM.

Comment: You can however run your Virtualbox boxes in QEMU/KVM instead of Virtualbox. The all your VMs would be running on KVM.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to run VirtualBox and Libvirt (KVM) at the same time because they both require full access to the cpu virtualization features.

[Some information on this](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kvm-virtualbox.html)

[Check this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/413545/594627)

Comment: Could you please include more information from those links? There are also more authoritative sources, such as the VirtualBox manual and the KVM FAQ which address this specifically.